# UICollectionView cells not displaying while UICollectionView background is

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

this is my class for ImageController (a ViewController)
Only the background of the collection view is displaying while the cells in it are not. Any help? Is there something I didn't initialize correctly?

Here is the class:

```
class ImageController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let reuseIdentifier = "imageCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ImageCell

        cell.myImage.image = unknown //name of image, isn't the cause of error

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you actually assign the delegate and datasource? I see you're VC is set up to conform to both, but you still have to say `collectionView.delegate = self` and `collectionView.dataSource = self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add in the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Also, try to debug the methods (add breakpoints and check if they are reachable).

Hope this helped.

Comment: That worked! Just a quick question: I have a similar class/controller that doesn't use those two lines of code, and it still works fine. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You probably added UICollectionViewController or connected delegates of UICollectionView on ViewController Scene.

Comment: @Shekar Yes I do, you might want to check the collectionView from the storyboard and see if they its delegate/dataSource are connected, or it maybe is a UICollectionViewController which will be automatically connected from the stoyrboard

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the lines of code mentioned above, just right click on the collectionView and drag to ViewController Scene the yellow space and select delegate and dataSoruce.
[image]